# Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I'm getting the above errors when I try to run `rails db:seed`, which uses `Sidekiq` to enqueue jobs for database generation. I've been trying a variety of fixes related to getting/setting the correct `REDISCLOUD_URL` variable without success.

My `redis.rb` file looks like this:

```
$redis = Redis.new

url = ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]

if url
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: url }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: url }
  end
  $redis = Redis.new(:url => url)
end
```

I'm sure the solution will be something to do with resolving `SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`, but having spent many hours trying to fix this I'm still stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey @Oscar - can you paste some examples of REDISCLOUD_URL ? It should look something like: `redis://username:password@hostname:port` but it can be quite varied. The SocketError is telling you that it cant resolve the hostname so the URL should make it easier to work out what is going wrong